# Failed to show data in tabs of a tabhost on android

Tags: android, web-services, android-tabhost

I have four activities namely,

- Demo_tabActivity.java  [main activity]
- Tabhost.java

The below two activities are tabs of the above tabhost.java

- Tab_1.java
- Tab_2.java

The first activity(`Demo_tabActivity.java`) contains an edittext & button.The second(`Tabhost.java`) activity contains a Tabhost widget.The third & fourth activities contains textviews respectively.

The first activity is going to consume a web service by getting the input from the user  and returns some data on first tab(third activity) of a tabhost(second activity).

Well consuming of webservice is working well and returns the value perfectly,

but, the problem is, its showing the result on the separate page instead of showing on the tabhost.

**Demo_tabActivity.java**

```
 public class Demo_tabActivity extends Activity 
 {

private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
   private static String METHOD_NAME = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
   private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
   private static String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";

   Button btnFar;
   EditText txtFar;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       btnFar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

       txtFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_in);

       btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
           String b;

         //Initialize soap request + add parameters
         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       

         //Use this to add parameters
         request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",txtFar.getText().toString());

         //Declare the version of the SOAP request
         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
         envelope.dotNet = true;

         try 
         {
             HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

             //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
             androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

             // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.

             SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

             if(result != null)
             {
              //Get the first property and change the label text

                b = result.toString();
                Intent itnt = new Intent(v.getContext(), Tab_1.class);
                itnt.putExtra("gotonextpage", b.toString());
                startActivity(itnt);
             }
             else
             {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NoResponse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
           }
         }
       });
       }
```

***NOTE: I've only doubt on if condition in the above code***

---

**Tab_1.java**

```
public class Tab_1 extends Activity 
{
TextView tv;
String result;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main2);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null)
{   result = extras.getString("gotonextpage");  }
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_main2);
tv.setText(result);
}}
```

**Tabhost.java**

```
 public class Tabhost extends TabActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);


    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tabhost.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("first").setIndicator("First").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab_2.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("second").setIndicator("Second").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shuld post your tabhost code too.

Comment: @Barak  please visit my question again,i've included tabhost.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because you aren't including Tab_1 in your tabhost (and you are self referencing TabHost... not sure how that's not causing a crash...).

I believe this line:

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tabhost.class);
```

needs to be changed to this (or add another TabSpec with it):

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab_1.class);
```